# Bash script: if any argument is "N" then function has extra options

Tags: linux, bash, shell

(I'll reuse this as it's about the same thing).
I have managed to make a usable script that does everything what's explained below the code block, except the order of the arguments, i.e.:

`./test.sh B N A`

will delete `B.zip`, create a new archive, but stops there, `A` will not be processed. It's fine, I can keep `N` as the last argument, no problem. Also, the `echo "no backup needed, removing"` does not work for some reason, but that's rather optional.

My question is: can what I have done be improved/altered somehow so that if there are other folders to be added in time the only changes to the script to be the `DIRx` entries? The biggest problem I see is modifying the block between `<start>` and `<stop>`. Here is the script:

---

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR1=A
DIR2=B
DIR3=C

bak()
{
    if [[ "$*" == N ]]
    then
        if [ $1 == N ]
        then
            :
        else
            echo "no backup needed, removing"
            rm -v $1.zip
        fi
    else
        if
            [ -f $1.zip ]
        then
            /bin/mv -vi $1.zip BKP/$1.zip_`/bin/date +"%H-%M"`
        else
            echo "no "$1".zip"
        fi
    fi
}

archive()
{
    if [ $* == N ]
    then
        :
    else
        if [ $1 == C ]
        then
            7z a -mx=9 $1.zip ../path/$1 -r -x\!$1/nope
        else
            7z a -mx=9 $1.zip $1 -r -x\!$1/bogus
        fi
    fi
}

########### <start> ####################
if [ -z "$*" ] || [[ "$#" -eq 1 && "$1" == N ]]
then
    bak "$DIR1"
    bak "$DIR2"
    bak "$DIR3"
    archive "$DIR1"
    archive "$DIR2"
    archive "$DIR3"
fi
############## <stop> #####################

#if [[ "$#" -eq 1 && "$1" == N ]]
#then
#   rm -v "$DIR1".zip
#   rm -v "$DIR2".zip
#   rm -v "$DIR3".zip
#   archive "$DIR1"
#   archive "$DIR2"
#   archive "$DIR3"
#fi

if [[ "$#" -gt 1 && "$*" == *N* ]]
then
    while [ "$#" -gt 1 ]
    do
        if [ "$1" == N ]
        then
            :
        else
            rm -v "$1".zip
        fi
        archive "$1"
        shift
    done
else
    while [ "$#" -ge 1 ]
    do
        bak "$1"
        archive "$1"
        shift
    done
fi
exit 0
```

---

Now, here's what I have and want it to do. The current directory holds the script, `test.sh`, and the folders `A` and `B`. `ls -AR` produces this:

```
A  B  test.sh

./A:
1.txt  2.txt  bogus

./B:
3.txt  4.txt  bogus
```

There is another folder, `C`, in `../path/`. The same `ls -AR ../path` gives this:

```
../path:
C

../path/C:
5.txt  6.txt  nope

../path/C/nope:
q.doc  w.rtf
```

What I want the script to do. When run with no arguments:

`./test.sh`

1) checks for existing zip archives in the current directory
1.a) if they exist, a backup is made for each with additional date suffix into `BKP/.`
2.a) if not, it lets you know
2) the three folders, `A`, `B` and `C` are archived, folders `A` and `B` without `A/bogus` and `B/bogus` and folder `C` without `../path/C/nope/*` and `../path/C/nope/` .

If run with arguments, these can be any of `A`, `B` or `C`, with an optional `N`. If run with `N`, only:

`./test.sh N`

then no archive check/backup will be performed, any archives already existent will be deleted and all 3 folders get archived. If run with any combination of `A`, `B` or `C`, for example:

`./test.sh A C`

then only archives `A.zip` and `C.zip` have a check and backup and only folders `A` and `C` are archived, `A` without `A/bogus` and `C` without `../path/C/nope/*` and `../path/C/nope/` . If run with any combination of `A`, `B` or `C`, but with additional `N`, i.e.:

`./test.sh B N C`

Then no check/backup is performed for `B.zip` and `C.zip`, the archives (if existent) get deleted and the folders `B` and `C` are archived.

The archives will have (inside) the folder as the root directory (i.e. open up the archive and you'll see `A`, `B` or `C` first) and all three of them have exceptions to the list of files to be processed: `A` and `B` don't need `bogus`, while `C` doesn't need subfolder `none` and anything inside it. I use `7z` instead of `zip` because I can write:

`7z a x.zip ../path/./C/bla/bla`

and have `C` as the root directory; I couldn't do it with `zip` (most likely I don't know how to, it doesn't matter as long as it works).

So far, the checking and the backup work. The archiving, if no exceptions are added and I remove the `$PATH` thing, work. The whole script doesn't. I would have posted every combination I have done so far, but 99% of them would have probably been impossible and the rest childish. I couldn't care less how it looks as long as it does the job.

---

Very optional: can an alias (or some sort) like "SCF" be made to "Supercalifragilistic"? The `C` folder has a rather long name (I could just make a symlink, I know). I have no idea about this one.

Comment: `$#` is a number; it will never match a pattern containing a letter.

Comment: I can't write in this comment about the changes, I'll update the post above.

Comment: as you're correctly using `shift` based on the value of `$#` (a number) in your while loop, you want to compare for Chars and Strings with `$1` of your input (and after you make a match,) that value is `shift`ed away, and you have a new value to test. **Edit**, now as you're using `$@` that is comparing against all remaining args haven't been `shift`ed away. That doesn't make sense.  I don't think tests like `$@ != *N*` are doing what  you want. Try `$@ !~ *N*` or better yet, read up about `case $var in *N*) echo matched N ;; esac`. Good luck.

Comment: I'll try digging up the net for the case $var, I also tried moving the bak loop outside with its own while loop, I may be on to something, but, right now, honestly, for someone who has never did bash scripting, being on this one for more than 6 hours now, I feel like really "bashing" it to pieces... I'll return later with some results.

Comment: Glad you're making progress. I should have mentioned earlier, this is quite a large problem to solve. Be sure to get good at dividing discrete parts of a problem into separate problems. That way you can see you're making progress, AND your development is not slowed down (until the end) by what are essentially integration issues. You want to know that all the little pieces are working by themselves, then start adding them together one-at-a-time, fixing problems that come up from "joining" two blocks of code, rather than issues from joining N blocks of code. Small is beautiful! Good luck.

Comment: I won't get to look at this again until later. You might consider deleting this question and reposting your revised problems. Better yet , several smaller questions are likely to get you more help. Try to make questions about 1 problem at a time. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, right now I found tldp.org and I'm trying to make something up from there. I won't be returning until tomorrow, hopefully with *something*.

Comment: I gave up. It implies too much learning for something I may be doing once a year, at its earliest. I'm not a programmer and I don't particularly like programming, so I'll just use that extra minute of my time to actually spell out the commands I want. Maybe scripts with commands only and named for each case in particular. It'll do. Either way, thank you both for the tips and helpful comments.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it. It's probably very childish and the worst possible script but I don't care right now, it works. Of course, if somebody has a better alternative to share, it's welcome, until then here's the whole script:

---

```
#!/bin/bash
# ./test.sh     = 1. searches for existing archives
#               1.a. if they exist, it backups them into BKP/.
#               1.b. if not, displays a message
#             2. archives all the directories in the array list
# ./test.sh N       = 1. deletes all the folder's archives existent and
#           specified in the array list
#             2. archives all the directories in the array list
# ./test.sh {A..F}  = 1. searches for existing archives from arguments
#               1.a. if they exist, it backups them into BKP/.
#               1.b. if not, displays a message
#             2. archives all the directories passed as arguments
# ./test.sh {A..F} N    = 1. deletes all the archives matching $argument.zip
#             2. archives all the directories passed as arguments

# The directories to be backed-up/archived, all in the current (script's) path
# except "C", on a different path
DIR=(A B C D E F)

# The back-up function, if any argument is "N", processing it is omitted
bak()
{
    if [[ "$*" == N ]]
    then
        :
    else
        if
            [ -f $1.zip ]
        then
            mv -vi $1.zip BKP/$1.zip_`date +"%H-%M"`
        else
            echo "$(tput setaf 1) no "$1".zip$(tput sgr0)"
        fi
    fi
}

# The archive function, if any argument is "N", processing it is omitted. Folder
# "C" has special treatment
archive()
{
    if [ $* == N ]
    then
        :
    else
        if [ $1 == C ]
        then
            7z a -mx=9 $1.zip ../path/$1 -r -x\!$1/nope
        else
            7z a -mx=9 $1.zip $1 -r -x\!$1/bogus
        fi
    fi
}

# case #1: no arguments
if [ -z "$*" ]
then
    for i in $(seq 0 $((${#DIR[@]}-1))) # counts from 0 to array-1
    do
        echo "$(tput setaf 2) backup$(tput sgr0)"
        bak "${DIR[i]}"
        archive "${DIR[i]}"
    done
    exit $?
fi

# case #2: one argument, "N"
if [[ "$#" -eq 1 && "$1" == N ]]
then
    for i in $(seq 0 $((${#DIR[@]}-1)))
    do
        echo "$(tput setaf 1) no backup needed, removing$(tput sgr0)"
        rm -v "${DIR[i]}".zip
        archive "${DIR[i]}"
    done
    exit $?
fi

# case #3: folders as arguments with "N"
if [[ "$#" -gt 1 && "$*" == *N* ]]
then
    while [ "$#" -gt 1 ]
    do
        if [ "$1" == N ]
        then
            :
        else
            echo "$(tput setaf 1) no backup needed, removing$(tput sgr0)"
            rm -v "$1".zip
        fi
        archive "$1"
        shift
    done
# case #4: folders as arguments without "N"
else
    while [ "$#" -ge 1 ]
    do
        echo "$(tput setaf 2) backup$(tput sgr0)"
        bak "$1"
        archive "$1"
        shift
    done
fi
exit $?
```

---