# Bash script: internal function alias for longer arguments

Tags: bash, alias

Suppose I have defined an array, like this:

`DIR=(A B Supercalifragilistic)`

and I need to invoke the script as

`./script A B Supercalifragilistic`

where the arguments are processed by internal functions `func1()` and `func2()`. Is there a way to make an alias (or anything, however it's called) `S` for `Supercalifragilistic` so that when I invoke:

`./script A B S`

the internal functions will process/interpret `S` as `Supercalifragilistic`?

Thank you in advance.

---

[edit]

I should add that the script is invoked via terminal, not inside a script, and the arguments `A B Supercalifragilistic`, or (hopefully) `S`, are passed on to the script in the terminal. I'm  sorry for the confusion.

---

[edit2]

The script is here: [Bash script: if any argument is "N" then function has extra options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155046/bash-script-if-any-argument-is-n-then-function-has-extra-options/23179861#23179861) , in the answer below. What it does is explained in the OP there, below the script. Finally, instead of `DIR=(A B C D E F)` it's `DIR=(A B Clarification D E F)` (it's just an example) and the folder `Clarification` is the only one in a different path than the rest. I hope it's more clear now, if not, please tell me.

---

[final edit, I hope]

I think I can shout "Evrika!". Your word "hardcoded" made me realize I *have* to modify the script anytime a new folder gets added/deleted, so I thought of making the array dynamic, as in
`./script a b "d e" g` results in `array=(a b "d e" g)`
but also that it should replace the long paths with some short ones (`Clarification >> C`), so I made this test script based on also the answers here:

```
#!/bin/bash

array=()

for i in "$@"
do
    if [[ "$i" == C ]]
    then
        array+=("Clarification")
    else
        array+=("$i")
    fi
done

echo ${array[*]}
echo

for i in $(seq 0 $(( $# - 1 )))
do
    echo ${array["$i"]}
done
```

and this is what it shows at command prompt:

```
$ ./x.sh abc C "d f" e
abc Clarification d f e

abc
Clarification
d f
e
```

I think now I can finally make the script to do what I want. Thank you, all, for the answers.

Comment: What is the relation with your original `DIR` array???

Comment: I updated the OP, I hope it explains more now. If you don't like the change, `Clarification` instead of `Supercalifragilistic`, just use `S` instead of `C`, it doesn't bother me.

Comment: You're way too verbose! can you explain exactly what you want in the following way: first the general rules (e.g., "given an array `A` and a string `S` I want blah blah") and then an example (e.g., "for example if my array is `A=(one two three)` and my string is `S=t` I want blah blah blah") in a limited number of words? In fact by doing that, you might even find the answer on your own, or decide that the problem is not well-posed.

Comment: Otherwise, are you aware of tab-completion? (I'm not sure it's relevant here, though).

Comment: The OP is rather long, true, but the script itself has the first lines as comments with what the script is supposed to do. `DIR=()` holds the names of the folders to be backed up and it's the only thing that needs to be changed in order for the script to work if other folders will be added/removed in the future. Currently, the only folders are `A B Clarification D E F`. `A B D E F` are in the same folder as the script, `Clarification` is in `../path/Clarification`. The `archive()` function has different conditions for it and only it. I don't know how shorter I can make this.

Comment: Tab completion would work if the folder was in the script's folder, but, unfortunately, it's the only one elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really have no idea what you exactly want to achieve! But I had a look at the script you linked in your last edit. Since you have a hard-coded array you might as well instead use an associative array:

```
declare -A dir_h
dir_h["A"]=A
dir_h["B"]=B
dir_h["C"]=../path/Clarification
dir_h["D"]=D
dir_h["E"]=E
```

to loop on the keys of `dir_h`, i.e., on `A B C D E`:

```
for k in "${!dir_h[@]}"; do
    echo "$k => ${dir_h[$k]}"
done
```

Try it, this might help you with your "alias" problem (or not).

---

Here's your script from your other post, using this technique and in a more consistent and readable form (note: I haven't tried it, there might be some minor typos, let me know if it's the case):

```
#!/bin/bash
# ./test.sh     = 1. searches for existing archives
#               1.a. if they exist, it backups them into BKP/.
#               1.b. if not, displays a message
#             2. archives all the directories in the array list
# ./test.sh N       = 1. deletes all the folder's archives existent and
#           specified in the array list
#             2. archives all the directories in the array list
# ./test.sh {A..F}  = 1. searches for existing archives from arguments
#               1.a. if they exist, it backups them into BKP/.
#               1.b. if not, displays a message
#             2. archives all the directories passed as arguments
# ./test.sh {A..F} N    = 1. deletes all the archives matching $argument.zip
#             2. archives all the directories passed as arguments

# The directories to be backed-up/archived, all in the current (script's) path
# except "C", on a different path

declare -A dir_h
dir_h["A"]=A
dir_h["B"]=B
dir_h["C"]=../path/Clarification
dir_h["D"]=D
dir_h["E"]=E
dir_h["F"]=F

declare -A nope_h
nope_h["A"]=bogus
nope_h["B"]=bogus
nope_h["C"]=nope
nope_h["D"]=bogus
nope_h["E"]=bogus
nope_h["F"]=bogus

die() {
   (($#)) && printf >&2 "%s\n" "$@"
   exit 1
}

bak() {

   if [[ "$1" != N ]]; then
      # Check that arg is in dir list:
      [[ -n ${dir_h["$1"]} ]] || die "Error in bak: argument \`$1' not handled"
      if [[ -f $1.zip ]]; then
         mv -vi "$1.zip" "BKP/$1.zip_$(date +"%H-%M")" || die
      else
         echo "$(tput setaf 1) no $1.zip$(tput sgr0)"
      fi
   fi
}

# The archive function, if any argument is "N", processing it is omitted. Folder
# "C" has special treatment
archive() {
   if [[ $1 != N ]]; then
      7z a -mx=9 "$1.zip" "${dir_h["$1"]}" -r -x\!"$1/${nope_h["$1"]}" || die
   fi
}

# Let's check once for all whether N is in the arg list
foundN=0
for a in "$@"; do [[ $a = N ]] && foundN=1 && break; done

if (($#==0)); then
   # case #1: no arguments
   for d in "${!dir_h[@]}"; do
      echo "$(tput setaf 2) backup$(tput sgr0)"
      bak "$d"
      archive "$d"
   done
elif (($#==1)) && ((foundN)); then
   # case #2: one argument, "N"
   for d in "${!dir_h[@]}"; do
      echo "$(tput setaf 1) no backup needed, removing$(tput sgr0)"
      rm -v "$d".zip || die
      archive "$d"
   done
elif (($#>1)) && ((foundN)); then
   # case #3: folders as arguments with "N"
   for f in "$@"; do
      if [[ $f != N ]]; then
         echo "$(tput setaf 1) no backup needed, removing$(tput sgr0)"
         rm -v "$f.zip" || die
      fi
      archive "$f"
   done
else
   for f in "$@"; do
      echo "$(tput setaf 2) backup$(tput sgr0)"
      bak "$f"
      archive "$f"
   done
fi
```

From this you can do a lot, and have pretty much infinite "alias" handling possibilities.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer, but this needs some chewing first. This is actually my 1st time writing a script (reading about how it's done, too), so even I am scared of the outcome, not counting commands as in `cd && zip && ls` (which are a handful, only). I'll try to understand what you did first, if I don't, I'll let you know, while trying to not ask for bash tutoring, either.

Comment: @Vlad good luck with all this! and be careful, a lot of information about bash that you'll find on the net is pure junk. If in doubt, refer to the [official manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html). If you need a sort of cookbook, refer to [the BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/) and if you need a tutorial, a good one (good as in: only shows good practices and written by guys who _really_ know bash) is [GreyCat and Lhunath's BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide).

Comment: I really don't know which answer to set as the answer, yours helped with the general setup and the hint about making it dynamic, "l0b0"'s with the substitution.

Comment: I thought about it and I gave you the answer, because you also corrected "Idriss Neumann" and "l0b0"'s answer resembles yours.

Comment: The `7z` command doesn't work and I think that `${Dir[$1]}` is the problem, because `$1` as an index doesn't return a number, but the string from the argument. So, the question: how to change the `$1` inside `[]` to return number for the array's index, rather than the argument entered in the terminal?

Comment: @Vlad My answer here relies only on associative arrays; there are no arrays at all (all keys are strings, and not numbers). So I don't really understand your question regarding _numbers_. Try not to confuse two distinct methods!

Comment: I have no idea what associative array means, but I guess it has to do with the `!` I missed. I'm sorry for the confusion, it does work. I have problems understanding the `die()` function, could you point out a few key points? Maybe links where I can read about them.

Comment: @Vlad the `die` function only prints its arguments on standard error and exits the script with exit code `1` (failure). The `(($#))` part is to check whether there are arguments given or not: in case of no arguments, nothing must be printed, only `exit 1` should be performed.

Answer (score 2):

No need to use an alias. You could try something like :

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

declare -a args
for arg in "$@"; do
    [[ $arg = "S" ]] && arg="Supercalifragilistic"
    args+=( "$arg" )
done

for arg in "${args[@]}"; do
    echo "$arg"
done
$ ./test.sh a b S e
a
b
Supercalifragilistic
e
```

Comment: Don't need the `i` variable at all. Use: `for arg in "$@"; do [[ $arg = "S" ]] && arg="Supercalifragilistic"; args+=( "$arg" ); done`

Comment: This is a good strategy: if you now need other "aliases", you can easily generalize the arg parsing loop: e.g., if you want to add `B` for `Banana` and `G` for `Gorilla`, replace the `[[ $arg = "S" ]] && arg="Supercalifragilistic"` by `case $arg in (B) arg=Banana; (G) arg=Gorilla;; (S) arg=Supercalifragilistic;; esac`.

Comment: Another comment `:D`: the OP might want to have the arguments put back in positional arguments: in this case you could build up your `args` array and set the positional arguments to that with `set -- "${args[@]}"`. You could also imagine doing the parsing with `args=(); while (($#)); do case $1 in (S) arg=Supercalifragilistic;; (*) arg=$1;; esac; args+=("$arg"); shift; done; set -- "${args[@]}"`

Comment: I tried this now, but it doesn't seem to work? I must be doing something wrong, I tried inserting in before `DIR=()`, after it but before the declaring of functions, after declaring of functions but before the function calls, after the functions. If I write `./script S` it just interprets `S` as `S`. Do I still need to have `DIR=(A B Supercalifragilistic)`, or `DIR=(A B S)`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need alias here. Just set variable `S` to your string:

```
S=Supercalifragilistic
```

and then use:

```
./script A B "$S"
```

OR else call your script directly using array:

```
./script ${DIR[@]}
```

**PS:** *It is not a good habit to use all caps variable names in shell and you can accidentally overwrite `PATH` variable some day.*

Comment: I just tried setting `S=Supercalifragilistic` before `DIR=(A B S)` and when I wrote `./script "$S"`, it interpreted it as if no argument was given. The `${DIR[@]}` thing also seems to me as if this needs to be called internally, inside the script. I suppose I should have mentioned that I call the script outside, from some folder, while the arguments are processed inside, I'll update the question.

Comment: You can just call your script as: `S=Supercalifragilistic; ./script A B "$S"`

Comment: I suppose I could, but that's just the thing that I want to avoid, typing long names when invoking the script. Otherwise I could simply write `./script A B Supercalifragilistic`, it's shorter :)

Comment: Place `S=Supercalifragilistic` in your `~/.bashrc` and call: `./script A B "$S"`

Comment: That would be one solution unless I move the script or install a new OS version with a different username. But that's easily changed. So far, this would be one thing to do. I'll wait some more, though, to see what other solutions might come. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
processed_directories=()
for dir in "${directories[@]}"
do
    if [ "$dir" = 'S' ]
    then
        dir='Supercalifragilistic'
    fi
    processed_directories+=("$dir")
done
```

It'll replace the value "S" with "Supercalifragilistic" anywhere in the array.

Comment: I think this would work if I wrote it before `DIR=(...)`, but this implies specific position of `S` to be the 3rd, but it could be anywhere in a variable number of arguments (within the nr. of `DIR`).

Comment: I really don't know which answer to set as the answer, yours helped with the substitution, "gniourf_gniourf"'s with the general setup and the hint about making it dynamic.