# Bash script: multiple arguments as exceptions

Tags: arrays, bash

[referring to [Bash script: internal function alias for longer arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23180080/bash-script-internal-function-alias-for-longer-arguments) , the accepted answer]

Is it possible to have multiple exceptions to add to the `archive()` function? For example:

```
7z a $1.zip ${dir_h[$1]} -r -x\!$1/EXCEPTION1 -x\!$1/EXCEPTION2
```

How to pass those two exceptions (or more) to the `nope_h` array?

Comment: Bash doesn't have "exceptions." What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The script in the link has an array that is passed as axceptions to the `archive()` function, but in my case (now) I have more than one exception, so the entry in the array should look like `nope_h["F"]="-x\!$1/exception1 -x\~$1/exception2" etc, but I cannot do that `$1` in the array, can I? I should add that until a few days ago I never tried to make a bash script involving more than a few commands all in a row, this is very advanced for me. (it's been a full day for me, I'll return in the morning)

Comment: You can use a third array for this...

Comment: Ah, you mean special cases.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Hello again, if it gets this complicated then I suppose it's best to just leave my current implementation: `if [[ $1 == C ]]; then <7z 1st list of exceptions>; else <7z 2nd list of exceptions> fi`, it works, but I was wondering if there was a cleaner, not too fluffy way of modifying the existing arrays. If another one is needed, that means extra changes whenever new folders get added/deleted, in which case it gets complicated. How to stop others replying now?

Comment: To stop others replying: you can't really... just leave the question as it is, and let posterity do its job! `:D`.